# Replace links in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this page that displays links from news sites. Everything works fine except for on one news site my links are followed by

```
,[object%20Object]
```

which makes the link unusable. How can I strip that away?
I would like the links that are generated to look like this:

```
www.example.com
```

Instead of like this:

```
www.example.com/,[object%20Object]
```

This is what I have:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function top_stories(o)
  {
    var items = o.query.results.item;
    var output = '';
    var no_items=items.length;
    for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++)
      {
        var title = items[i].title;
        var link = items[i].link;
        var desc = items[i].description;
        output += "<li><a href='" + link + "'>"+title+"</a></li>";
      }
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='results'></div>
  <script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fbreitbart%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=top_stories'>
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a link to the page http://sspencer10.com/test.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` property on the item is an array.  You want `link[0]` which is the short URL of the item or `link[1].href` which is the actual URL.

```
function top_stories(o)
{
  var items = o.query.results.item;
  var output = '';
  var no_items=items.length;
  for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++)
    {
      var title = items[i].title;
      var link = items[i].link[1].href;
      var desc = items[i].description;
      output += "<li><a href='" + link + "'>"+title+"</a></li>";
    }
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `items[i].link` isn’t a string.

Instead it’s an `Array`:

```
[
  "http://short-url.for/example.com",
  {
    href: "http://www.example.com/",
    rel: "standout"
  }
]
```

To fix this problem, instead get the first element `[0]` of `items[i].link`:

```
var link = items[i].link[0];
```

or the `href` property of the second element, which is the actual link:

```
var link = items[i].link[1].href;
```

When you convert a JavaScript `Array` into a `String`, it is equivalent to `array.join(",")`; and when you convert a JavaScript `Object` into a `String`, it becomes `"[object Object]"`.

So, in other words:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function top_stories(o)
  {
    var items = o.query.results.item;
    var output = '';
    var no_items=items.length;
    for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++)
      {
        var title = items[i].title;
        var link = items[i].link[1].href;
        var desc = items[i].description;
        output += "<li><a href='" + link + "'>"+title+"</a></li>";
      }
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='results'></div>
  <script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fbreitbart%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=top_stories'>
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```